# "I chose the USA because I love speaking English and am good at it"is this correct?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

"I chose the USA because I love speaking English and am good at it"

It's for a past event, should it be "I loved....and was good..." instead (even though it's still true today)?

Answer (score 1):

Either one of these seems fine, but the implications are a bit different.

> I chose the USA because I love speaking English, and I'm good at it.

This implies to me that your feelings about English haven't changed.

> I chose the USA because I loved speaking English, and I was good at it.

Whereas this implies that something has changed since then, or some other factor is more important; I would expect to see that usage in a context like this:

> I chose the USA because I loved speaking English, and I was good at it, but now I miss hearing my native language.

(Note also that I would in both cases say "... and I am/I was good at it" instead of "... and am/was good at it").

Comment: . . . and I am good at it, but I also miss hearing my native language.